# Display a DIV across 2 frames in HTML

Tags: html, css, iframe, web, frames

Hi I have a page with two frames. I need a define a div in a top frame, such that it gets displayed over bottom frames also.

```
------------------------------------------------
|               Frame 1               '<myDiv>'|
|                                     '       '|
|-------------------------------------'       '|
|                                     '       '|
|                                     '-------'|
|                                              |
|               Frame 2                        |
|                                              |
|                                              |
|                                              |
-----------------------------------------------|

<frameset rows="*" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" id="titleFrame" framespacing="0">
  <frame src="title.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" id="titleFrameDiv" noresize="noresize" title="title" />
      <frameset id="myFrameDiv" rows="100%,*" cols="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
       <frame src="main.html" id="mainFrame" name="mainFrame" scrolling="Auto" title="main" />
      </frameset>
  </frameset>
```

Its ok, even I need to change this to iframes.
How can I do this in my current design..

Comment: No way. Use `iframe`s

Comment: Even iframes is ok. Can you help me.

Comment: Well, with iframes your div will be outside of both iframes, beside them

Comment: just make that div as absolute positioned and place it at top by giving top=0 and right = 0 add z-index if required

Answer (score 0):

The closest you could come would be to have a duplicate of the div in each document.

You can then use fixed CSS positioning to line them up.

Comment: @C-linkNepal — Only until the user scrolls one of the frames.