# Chosen plugin cuts between different frames. (Js jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen, frames

I got a chosen selectbox in a frame, and another frame almost exactly below it. Now my selectbox is cut, but I have to make it work! I guess it's something in the chosen js, because a normal selectbox can overlap between different frames.

Example:
[image: Example]

Please help me, I'm struggling with this for a long time and I really need to solve it. I wish I could cut out all of the frames, but I'm afraid that isn't possible.

Comment: Doesn't the plugin "select" build a sort of pretend select element out of other elements? So they'll all stay within their frame.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880385/display-a-div-across-2-frames-in-html

Comment: @Quentin I don't really see a solution in there, except duplicating and positioning. This really doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Grafit — It's not a good problem. Frames are a bad idea. Using divs instead of select elements is a bad idea. Using them together is a bad idea that works poorly. There isn't a good solution.

Comment: I know. I'm doing an internship and they chose this option a long time ago. It's too much work in my period as an intern to change all of this, so I really just can't.