# Bring DIV tag to front in FRAMESET

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

In a particular web page I've used frameset to display set of pages content in a single page, I divided my frame to top(Menu frame 100%) followed by left frame and right frame below to the top frame.

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="85,*" cols="*" FRAMEBORDER=1 BORDER=1 bordercolor=#ffffff>
        <FRAME src="<asp:Literal id=litMenuSkinURL runat=server/>" name=top id="menuFrame" scrolling=no>
        <FRAMESET rows="*" COLS="215,*" bordercolor=#ffffff>
            <FRAME src="WVTreeList.aspx?mode=0" name=framTreeList scrolling=1 frameborder=1>
            <FRAME name=framAnalysis src="<asp:Literal id=litAnalysisURL runat=server/>" scrolling=1>
        </FRAMESET>
    </FRAMESET>
```

But when i click on Menu from top frame It's hiding entire menu in the back of left and right frames and I can't see my sub menu which is a collection of sub menu data in a DIV tag.

Previously I've used 'window.createpopup()' method to bring DIV tag to front which is not supported now in IE>11 and other browsers, so how can i bring DIV tag to front of left and right frames? Is there any other way?

Below is the way that I've tried but it's not working only top menu is loading that to with some width not 100% and no other frame is loading.

```
<style type="text/css">
             #wrapper { width: 100%; margin:0px auto; overflow:hidden; }
#header { width: 100%; height:100px; }
#leftCol { width: 25%; float:left; }
#rightCol { width: 75%; float:right; }
            </style>
    </HEAD>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header">
          <iframe src="<asp:Literal id=litMenuSkinURL runat=server/>" />
     </div>

     <div id="leftCol">
          <iframe src="WVTreeList.aspx?mode=0"/>
     </div>

     <div id="rightCol">
          <iframe src="<asp:Literal id=litAnalysisURL runat=server/>" />  <!-- Set Div As your requirement -->
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880385/display-a-div-across-2-frames-in-html

Comment: Did you try `pointer-events: none;` CSS.

Comment: Where i need add pointer-events:none; ??

Comment: Please provide some working example on jsBin.com or some similar resource.